# PHP Results in Email with Cyrillic characters

Tags: php

I have used a php form for a while now and have got good results.

From here: http://www.dreamweaverclub.com/dreamweaver-php-form.php

Issue I now have is that I have users now in Russia and results are coming to me in some garbled format such as "Ð¥ÐµÐ»ÑŒÑÐ¸Ð½ÐºÐ¸" instead of Russian text.

Can anyone advise how to edit the php from that link above so that the results would come to me as plain text email including Russian characters?

I guess its something to do with not having any reference to UTF-8 but I have no idea how to implement that.

Thanks ...

Comment: I have seen the previous post you refer to, but I don't find the solution to my specific case there.

Comment: I wanted to know how to edit the specific code that I had in order to display Cyrillic characters in the email results.